# React - Call javascript function after ajax returned data has been rendered

Tags: reactjs

I have the following data loader component in react. It fetches data from API endpoint and renders HTML with that data.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
class DataLoader extends Component {

          static propTypes = {
             endpoint: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
             render: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
             callback: PropTypes.func
          };

          state = {
             data: [],
             loaded: false,
             placeholder: "Loading..."
          };

        componentDidMount() 
        {
             fetch(this.props.endpoint)
               .then(response => {
                   if (response.status !== 200) {
                   return this.setState({ placeholder: "error" });
               }

               return response.json();
             })
            .then(data => this.setState({ data: data, loaded: true } ))
            .then(  this.props.callback );
       }

       render() {
           const { data, loaded, placeholder } = this.state;
           return loaded ? this.props.render(data) : <p>{placeholder}</p>;
       }
}

export default DataLoader;
```

Here is App.jsx file

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import DataLoader from "./DataLoader"; 
import EventDivs from "./EventDivs";


 const App = () => (
     <DataLoader endpoint="api/v1/calendarevents/" 
               render={data => <EventDivs data={data} />}
               callback = {function() {
                   console.log($("#renderedDiv").length);
               }} 
     />
 );


const appid = document.getElementById("app");
appid ? ReactDOM.render(<App />, appid ) : null;
```

`console.log($("#renderedDiv").length)` gets `0`, because `this.props.callback` is callback of `fetch`.

I want to know how to call the function after the data that Ajax returned has been rendered?

Comment: Could you try using the **setState** callback like: `.then(data => this.setState({ data: data, loaded: true }, this.props.callback ))` and removing the `.then(this.props.callback)`

Comment: @jpacareu Yes, I have tried it , but with no luck

Comment: Please check out what I did [here](https://codepen.io/javierpacareu/pen/wEwMPv?editors=0011) and try the same on your issue

Comment: @jpacareu , thank you for your example. It really helped me.